# Browser compatibility issue with page logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have a logo at the top of my page. It appears great in Opera. But in IE9 and Chrome25 this section is not visible. How I can I resolve this?  http://jsbin.com/eqokec/4/

javascript

```
<style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            background: url("img/brick.jpg") repeat;
            height: 95%;
            font-size: 100%;
            margin-top: 2.5%;
        }

        .logo {
            min-height: 20% !important;
            background: url('img/logo.jpg') center no-repeat;
            background-size: auto 60%;
        }

        #container {
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 60%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            min-height: 100%;
            border: none;
            -moz-border-radius: 25;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25;
            border-radius: 25;
        }

        table {
            width: 98%;
            clear: none;
        }

        th {
            float: left;
        }

        span {
            color: #802420;
        }
        dl{
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:top;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        dt { float: left;  overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
        dt b,td b{color: #499249; text-decoration: underline}
        dd{ float: right;  overflow: hidden; text-indent: 3px;}
        /*dd:before{content: ".........................."}*/
        img { max-width: 100%; }
        img#street_view{
            width: 60%;
        }

        *{
            font-family: verdana arial sans-serif;
        }
        @media (max-width:639px){body{font-size: .5rem;margin: 0;padding: 0;}#container{width: 100%;}}
        @media (min-width: 640px) { body {font-size: .5rem;}#container{width: 50%} }
        @media (min-width:960px) { body {font-size: .7rem;}#container{width: 50%} }
        @media (min-width:1100px) { body {font-size:.9rem;}#container{width: 50%}}
    </style>
```

html

```
<section id="container">
<div class="logo">
    <h2><a href="/" title="Luigi's Pizzeria"></a></h2>
</div>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#locations">Locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Put an absolute image path in your demo. It's hard to troubleshoot when the image doesn't load.

Comment: @isherwood I've made that change. The link above has be edited for the lastest revision. Thanks

Comment: `.logo {
            min-height: 20% !important;` should be `#container .logo {
            min-height: 20%;` and the `#container` declaration should go above `#container .logo`. http://jsbin.com/eqokec/7/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to class `.logo` `display: block;` and `height: 200px;` or something similar...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want a larger minimum height.

```
.logo {
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amend

```
#container {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

To

```
#container {
        height: 100%;
    }
```